# kohana setting url for Ajax Modal Form

Tags: php, ajax, forms, kohana, modal-dialog

I have a Kohana controller, and a route corresponding to it.
also, i want to make a form that will appear as a ajax modal, when a user clicks a link. The problem is: i want this form to be controlled by a different controller action, and of course, because i am using exactly the same data as in the view using the first controller action, i will have exactly the same parameters (in the second controller action). 
The problem is that, having the same parameters and only different actions, my both controlers's routes will point in the same page. So...

How can i make an ajax modal form that will use exactly the same variables that the view in which i am putting the link to the modal form is using? is it indicated to make another controller action?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just should create 2 different views.